# How to change the timezone of Oracle SQL Developer / Oracle Data Modeler?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Each time I run Oracle SQL Developer or Oracle Data Modeler I receive this error message:

> ora-01882 "timezone region not found"

Digging a this issue, I found that both Oracle SQL Developer and Oracle Data Modeler says that my timezone is `Europe/Berlin`, which is not listed into the Oracle's system view `V$TIMEZONE_NAMES`.

So, I need to change the timezone in Oracle SQL Developer (not the database) to match the most similar timezone found in `V$TIMEZONE_NAMES`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you need to [change the time zone of Oracle SQL Developer](http://mariuzzo.com/tips/changing-the-time-zone-of-oracle-sql-developer.html) (or Oracle Data Modeler), then this is how to do it:

1. Go to the installation directory of Oracle SQL Developer.
2. Open the file located at: `sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf`.
3. At the end of file, add the following line: `AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=GMT-4`.

You will need to change the value `GMT-4` to one that match one of the timezones in `V$TIMEZONE_NAMES`.

And that’s it!

Comment: Why GMT not a default configuration for a fresh install of sqldeveloper?

Comment: Where's the file location in MACOS

Comment: @JianwuChen In MAC can get `sqldeveloper.conf` in the following location: 

`/Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf`

Answer (score 9):

Try:

- Oracle Sql Developer 4.1.3
- Open config file.
- sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf
- Add end of the file.
- AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=GMT
- Restart your Oracle Sql Developer.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me

```
AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=GMT+5
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

1)

When in Windows 8, make sure you have authorization/rights over the sqldeveloper folder
(for me this is C:\Program Files\sqldeveloper, do a right-mouse click here and choose "Properties..." and then "Security" tab and on that tab press the "Edit" button and give yourself all the rights. [I have to guess these names in English because my Windows is not English)]

2) then follow the steps from Rubens Mariuzzo above, except the last one

3) AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=GMT+1

SELECT * FROM v$timezone_names gave me both Europe/Amsterdam and Europe/Berlin as options (both are GMT+1 but my location is Europe/Amsterdam). However using either of these names stil gave the ora-01882 "timezone region not found", only after changing to "timezone=GMT+1" did the bug disappear

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=GMT+7
```

Tq

Answer (score -2):

Sri lanka
AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=GMT+5.30