# Oracle to_date() return incorrect date with +2 days

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle to_date() function return incorrect date with +2 days.

Please take a look on screenshot

[image]

Why is it happened?

Comment: For `select to_date('11-MAY-18', 'DD-MON-YYYY') from dual;`
Oracle returns `13-MAY-18`

Comment: Don't know. Some mismatch between current dates on server and client? What does `select sysdate, current_date from dual` return?

Comment: Try setting the session date format as - alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'; ..... run your query after this and see if the issue still persists.

Comment: What is the client tool ? The select is returning an Oracle date value to the client and the client is responsible for interpreting that and rendering it to your screen.

Comment: Looks like SQL Developer. Check the timezone settings of SQL Developer and the database server. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864015/how-to-change-the-timezone-of-oracle-sql-developer-oracle-data-modeler

Comment: Please run this query: `SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters` and append it's result to the question. Without knowing your session parameters **the issue cannot be reproduced**, thus I am voting to close your question.

Comment: What do you get from `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1-MAY-18', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not matching the format you are providing.

Year is provided as 18 and TO_DATE expects 2018.

Below should work fine:

```
select to_date('11-MAY-18', 'DD-MON-YY') from dual;
```

OR

```
select to_date('11-MAY-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY') from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't replicate your result, but I do get the wrong date for `1-MAY-18` on SQL Fiddle even if a date literal is used (but not if I use my Oracle 11g instance or [Oracle 18c on Oracle's Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/) website):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/360)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( '1-MAY-18', 'DD-MON-YYYY' ),
       DATE '0018-05-01',
       TO_DATE( '1-MAY-18', 'DD-MON-RR' )
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/360/0)**:

```
| TO_DATE('1-MAY-18','DD-MON-YYYY') |     DATE'0018-05-01' | TO_DATE('1-MAY-18','DD-MON-RR') |
|-----------------------------------|----------------------|---------------------------------|
|              0018-04-29T00:00:00Z | 0018-04-29T00:00:00Z |            2018-05-01T00:00:00Z |
```

You will note that the `YYYY` format model and the numeric value `18` gives the year `18 AD` and not `2018 AD`. To fix this you need to either give the entire 4-digit year or use the `RR` format model.