# Unable to connect SQL Developer in Mac OS

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
ORA-00604: Error occurred at recursive SQL Level 1
ORA-01882 timezone region not found
```

Where to define the timezone ? SQL DEVELOPER not installed in MAC.

Comment: What region is your Mac set to (in System Preferences->Language & Region)?Sounds like it's one your DB doesn't know about... It's probably going to be simpler to change that setting to a common region, or override the Java locale in the SQL Developer launch process - the best way/place to do what might depend on the version you are using.

Comment: Time Zone is set as +05:30. How to override the Java locale in sql Developer Launch process ?

Comment: duplicate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864015/how-to-change-the-timezone-of-oracle-sql-developer-oracle-data-modeler