# Unable to connect Oracle database using SQL Developer in MACOS. Time zone error

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using MAC OS. SQL Developer is not installed. Only zip file is in apolication folder. And when I click on the zip file, it extracts only one file - `SQLDevelopr.exe`. No others files or folders. Where do I find `.conf` file? And add my timezone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect SQL Developer in Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190965/unable-to-connect-sql-developer-in-mac-os)

Comment: you have to open the App, there's a Resources folder in there...keep digging from there