# Oracle timezone offset differs when run in sqlplus vs sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Here's a puzzler.  Take the following query and execute in oracle sqldeveloper:

```
select to_char(CAST (sysdate AS  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) ,'TZH:TZM') dst,    
           to_char(CAST (sysdate-160 AS  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) ,'TZH:TZM') nodst    
 from dual;
```

you will get the results of "-04:00", "-05:00".  This gives the correct dst-adjusted timezone offset (eastern) with one date in dst, and the other not.  Running the same query from sqlplus gives both values as "-4:00".  This is causing a problem for a package that when called from sqlplus shows the incorrect value also.

Comment: What are session time zones in both clients? [This is the same effect](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8cc9075db3d0c753d23dbac031995afb) - not saying you have exactly those values, of course, but they appear to be different. (Why are you converting sysdate, rather than just using systimestamp? Maybe just as an example date?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cast to a timestamp with time zone, Oracle has to choose which time zone to use; and it uses the current session time zone. It's equivalent to doing:

```
select to_char(FROM_TZ(CAST (sysdate AS  TIMESTAMP), SESSIONTIMEZONE) ,'TZH:TZM') dst,    
           to_char(FROM_TZ(CAST(sysdate-160 AS  TIMESTAMP), SESSIONTIMEZONE) ,'TZH:TZM') nodst    
 from dual;
```

As you are getting different results in SQL Developer and SQL*Plus, you seem to have different session time zones in those two clients. You can check by querying `sessiontimezone` in each. SQL Developer sets the session time zone from the Java time zone (picked up from the operating system by default; you can override that by [passing a `user.timezone` value at start-up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14864018/266304)). SQL*Plus [uses the `ORA_SDTZ` environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-578B5988-31E2-4D0F-ACEA-95C827F6012B), so you can set that to match your locale if you don't want to set it from within the database with `alter session` (manually or via `login.sql`); and if unset it defaults to 'OS_TZ':

> The default value of the `ORA_SDTZ` variable, which is used when the variable is not set or it is set to an invalid value, is `'OS_TZ'`.

... and it's picking that up as an offset (-04:00) rather than a region.

If you always want the result to be in a particular time zone regardless of any user's session settings, then you can state which one to use instead, e.g.:

```
select to_char(FROM_TZ(CAST (sysdate AS  TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') ,'TZH:TZM') dst,    
           to_char(FROM_TZ(CAST(sysdate-160 AS  TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') ,'TZH:TZM') nodst    
 from dual;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a72263e27ac19da446fdf64d647832ef) with several session settings to demonstrate.

Presumably your real query is working from a variable date value, not `sysdate`; otherwise you could use `systimestamp` instead, with `at time zone` to adjust to a different zone if necessary.

Comment: If you are going to use the date/time component (rather than just the time zone component) then you want to use `CURRENT_DATE` rather than `SYSDATE` since you want the session time and not the system time when you are also using `SESSIONTIMEZONE`.

Comment: True; also true if you do only want time zone really, in case you happen to be looking at a date/time around a DST switch. (Though I still think sydate/current_date is probably just a placeholder for a real date in the question...)

Comment: The answer would be clearer if it also explained what the OP observed. You hinted at that in your question below the original post. Very likely, the session time zone (saved in settings somewhere) for the SQL Developer session is `'America/New_York'` (which then is DST-aware), while the default session time zone for the SQL\*Plus session is a hard-coded `'-04:00'`. I use the same interfaces, and I don't recall ever messing with these settings, so I must have the out-of-the-box defaults; and indeed they are similar to what I described (except for Los Angeles rather than New York).

Answer (score 2):

> This gives the correct dst-adjusted timezone offset (eastern) with one date in dst, and the other not.

No, it gives you a manually adjusted value that appears to be correct; however, when DST ends then your query will be incorrect and it will require adjusting ... then next spring it will require adjusting again ... and next autumn.

If you want the correct values then let Oracle adjust the time zones (and you don't need to cast `SYSDATE` to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, you can just use `SYSTIMESTAMP` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`):

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern', 'TZH:TZM')
         AS timezone
FROM   DUAL
```