# How to change timezone of oracle sql developer in mac os

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting the following error while I am trying to connect to Oracle SQL Developer:

Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found

I know changing timezone will help, but how to do so in mac os?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the timezone of Oracle SQL Developer / Oracle Data Modeler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864015/how-to-change-the-timezone-of-oracle-sql-developer-oracle-data-modeler)

Comment: Same as answer shared above...in Mac, add the jvm options to your product.conf file, in your $HOME\.sqldeveloper\system20.4.1.... folder